# Unreachable statement explanation required

Tags: java

I'm preparing for OCA Java exam and got this question wrong. I can't see why the `return` statement is unreachable. My thinking is that even if an exception is thrown it will be caught, the statement in the finally block executed and then the return statement is executed, or is it the case that the thread does not execute the return statement if an exception is thrown? More generally, can somebody explain the rules of what happens in the case of an exception being fired and in which cases statements after the finally block are executed or not. For some questions I am getting this correct and for others I am not so I am not clear on the exact compiler rules here.

```
public float parseFloat(String s){
   float f = 0.0f;
   try{
      f = Float.valueOf(s).floatValue();
      return f ;
   }
   catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
      System.out.println("Invalid input " + s);
      f = Float.NaN ;
      return f;
   }
   finally { System.out.println("finally");  }
   return f ;
}
```

Comment: Because one of the `return f;` statements in the `try/catch` block *will* run.

Comment: @August That is not taken into consideration by the Java compiler analysis engine here - a *different* Exception could also be thrown in the try (ensuring that there is no return value), such that neither return is run. That is, replace `Float.valueOf(s).floatValue()` with `float f()`, the contents of which are not important - the analysis does not change.

Comment: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=296 . if there is no exception, finally occurs ( right BEFORE the first return f; ) once it is done it returns ( then don't call last return f). If there is a NumberFormatException, same applies and last possibility is an Exception that is NOT a NumberFormatException in that case exception is not catched then it is passed to parent BUT finally will occur, at end of finally exception will be passed. Then last return f is never reached. finally is called always and let last action in stand by to complete it at end of finally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If an exception occurs, the code drops out immediately
2. It then checks, if there is a matching catch statement and if it does, it's code then runs
3. regardless of what happens inside of the *try* or the *catch* blocks, the finally part will always run.
4. if the catch block did not make a return OR throw an exception itself, the code after the try/catch/finally continues to run.
5. this is not possible in your code, because in the success case your try block does return and in the fail-case your catch block returns.

so there might be a theoretical case, where your code would make sense: If the code inside the try{} block would throw any other exception besides NumberFormatException. This is only possible, if it is an *unchecked exception* (the ones you are not required to catch). The compiler cannot know or check this, therefore such code is not allowed unless you write a second catch block for it. (if you are confused now: forget what I said, it's not important for your task)

here is a sample of such a case:

```
public float parseFloat(String s){
   float f = 0.0f;
   try{
      SomeOtherClass.doStuffWhichFailsWithRuntimeException();
      return f;
   }
   catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
       // will not run, because the thrown exception is not of type NumberFormatException
   }catch(Exception e){
       // any other failure besides NumberFormatException
       // considered bad practice: If you do not know what fails, do not try to recover from it, it's most likely very bad.
      return f;
   }
   finally { 
      // this will run after the catch block was run
      System.out.println("finally");  
   }

   // theoretically reachable, but compiler does not allow it because he cannot check it.
   //return f ;
}
```

Comment: The last bit is *very* important to keep in mind on how the Java analysis works, good job pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

If an exception is occured then catch block runs, f is returned and finally block runs next.
The last

> return f;

will never be reached.

Comment: What if a *different* (non NumberFormatException) exception was thrown? The Java analysis does *not* consider which exception, if any, was thrown (or is possibly throwable from the code in the try).

Comment: @user2864740 Then the application is probably beeing terminated as with all uncaught excetions

Comment: @Gumbo Probably, however such is important to consider in such analysis.